# How can make this possible through shell script? When I try to build ipa facing error Signing requires a development team

Tags: xcode, shell, cordova, ionic-framework, ipa

> I am using shell script for generate the ipa build. While build the ipa through the shell script the following error is came. Is there any possible to overcome this error through the command.

**error: Signing for "stage123" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'stage123')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command this will select a devlopment team,

`ionic cordova build ios --device -- --developmentTeam="<TEAM ID>"`